# Rest Service with Java Observable from Executer Service

Tags: java, rest, rx-java, blocking, nonblocking

I have a rest web service which returns DeferredResults. I implemented JavaRx Observable from executer service that returns Future. I wanted this web service to be non blocking but it seems it is blocking the operation.

Do you think the way I used executer service is healthy?

```
DeferredResult result = new DeferredResult();
    Observable<ResultEntity> observable = Observable
                    .from(executerService.submit(callable));
            observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<ResultEntity>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    result.setErrorResult(throwable.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResultEntity r) {
                    result.setResult(t);

                }

            });
```

Comment: Did you see this http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/

Comment: Thank you. I also used CompatableFuture before in order to build a non-blocking service and it worked. But I would like to know about RxJava and how I can create a non-blocking service with it. This was the reason I askes this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Observable.from(Future)` is blocking operation, as mentioned in documentation. You should use `Observable.from(Future,Scheduler)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Callable`, you can use `fromCallable`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(callable)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executorService))
.subscribe(...)
```